# Why my list comprehension doesn't work with a plot and datetime?

Tags: python, matplotlib, list-comprehension

I'm making a plot using matplotlib and trying to use list comprehension.

When I use only one argument for `ax.plot(highs)`, it works:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filename = "data/sitka_weather_07-2018_simple.csv"
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    # Get the highest temperatures from CSV.
    highs = [int(row[5]) for row in reader]

    # Make a plot of the highest temperatures.
    plt.style.use("bmh")
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(dates, c="red")

    # Reformat the plot.
    plt.title("Daily high temperatures, July 2018", fontsize=24)
    plt.xlabel("", fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel("Temperature (F)", fontsize=16)
    plt.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=16)

    plt.show()
```

But when I use an additional argument `dates`,

```
# Get the highest temperatures and dates from CSV.
highs = [int(row[5]) for row in reader]
dates = [datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y-%m-%d") for row in reader]

# Make a plot of the highest temperatures.
plt.style.use("bmh")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, highs, c="red")

# Reformat the plot.
plt.title("Daily high temperatures, July 2018", fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel("", fontsize=16)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel("Temperature (F)", fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=16)

plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python_work\sitka_highs.py", line 25, in <module>
    ax.plot(dates, highs, c="red")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1688, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 311, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 504, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (0,) and (31,)
```

When I use a simple for loop for `highs` and `dates`, it works:

```
# Get the highest temperatures and dates from CSV.
dates, highs = [], []
for row in reader:
    current_date = datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y-%m-%d")
    high = int(row[5])
    dates.append(current_date)
    highs.append(high)
```

My question is: what am I doing wrong with list comprehension?

Comment: `reader` is an *iterator*.  After iterating over it once, there are no items left in it, so any further attempt at iteration is going to produce nothing.  Since you do need to use the data more than once, try `reader = list(reader)` to change it to a form that can be reused.

Comment: yep, what @jasonharper said. You could, if you really want, skip back to the start of the file with `f.seek(0)` between the list comprehensions, but there's no reason why you would want to read the whole file twice. I would suggest the loop you use at the end is probably the better, more efficient option here